# Rails - generate scaffold for multi select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-generate

I used the following method to generate scaffold for platform list in our app:

```
rails generate scaffold platform name:string url:string country:string
```

I would like to still use scaffold possibility to add additional attributes, like type and gender, which should be drop downs, or preferably multi-select's.

Is there a way to use rails generate to create such a models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already generated a scaffold for Platform. So you have two options:

- edit scaffold by hand to add the new fields (recommended)
- remove scaffold with `rails destroy scaffold` and then use `rails generate` again

Anyway scaffolding doesn't allow you to specify options for a drop-down menu. In any case you have to manually edit the scaffold. Furthermore in Rails migrations you cannot specify ENUM fields, so the best option for gender would be a string field with unitary length (with a `validates_inclusion_of` in model).

P.S. Don't use `type` as a column name because you will probably get strange behaviors.